# Creating a socket for IPv6 and IPv4 with Windows XP support

Tags: sockets, ipv6

For modern operating systems, dual-stack[1] IPv6 socket does everything.

However, Windows XP is still used by many people in China, we cannot ignore Windows XP support. Unfortunately Windows XP does not support dual-stack IPv6 socket. [2]

So my approach is:

1. Try to create an IPv6 socket and set it to dual-stack.
2. If success, keep using it.
3. If failed, close IPv6 socket(if exists) then create an IPv4 socket.

Am I going the right way? I assume there is no one who uses IPv6-only internet connection with Windows XP.

---

[1]: call setsockopt with IPV6_V6ONLY=0.

[2]: Windows XP with no Service Pack supports no IPv6. Windows XP with Service Pack >=1 supports IPv6 without dual-stack.

Comment: Windows XP will not support IPv6 at all unless it has been specifically installed on a workstation. Can you guarantee this has been done?

Comment: You can still install SP3, and you can require that users do so. Everybody should have gotten this long ago.